# Arduino mini being programmed with CH340G

Tags: programming, arduino-mini

So, I have bought this USB programmer with CH340G chip on it, but it seems, that I cannot program arduino mini clone.

So, this programmer has pinout of 5V|GND|TX|RX|3V3.

I have connected TX to TX and RX to RX (and also switched, because these programmers sometimes have marked where certain pins supposed to go, not what they represent).

I have also wired the DSR leg from the chip and connected it to the RESET on arduino mini clone.

There's still no connection between them.

Now I'm wondering, if I just connect the power supply and TX and RX connectors, when am I supposed to press reset for the succesfull programming?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should connect the DTR (not the DSR) pin to the reset terminal WITH a 100nF capacitor. See [this page](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/AutoResetRetrofit) or [the arduino uno schematics](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf) to see how to put the capacitor (it's simply in series with the signal.

However I suggest you to start programming WITHOUT the autoreset; once you are sure that you can program it then try soldering that capacitor to program the arduino without having to hit the reset button.

As for when, watch the IDE status: when it stops compiling and shows the "Uploading" string, press the reset button on the board. You will usually have a couple of seconds to press it.